# Casting a string to a double results in null values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, double, databricks

My dataset is here: https://www.kaggle.com/code/sfbruno/mining-quality-xgboost/data

Example CSV data:

```
date,% Iron Feed,% Silica Feed
2017-03-10 01:00:00,"55,2","16,98"
2017-03-10 01:00:00,"55,2","16,98"
2017-03-10 01:00:00,"55,2","16,98"
```

And I have this code:

```py
sourcefile = 'MiningProcess_Flotation_Plant_Database.csv'
df = spark.read.format('csv').option("header","true").load(db_ws.dp_engagement + '/' + sourcefile)
display(df)
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,BooleanType,DateType,DoubleType
df2 = df.withColumn("% Iron Feed",col("% Iron Feed").cast(DoubleType())) 
df2.printSchema()
```

The type is changed:

```
root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- % Iron Feed: double (nullable = true)
 |-- % Silica Feed: string (nullable = true)
```

However, when I display the dataframe again:

```
display(df2)
```

The Iron Feed is all null.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the decimal separator which is `,` in your data. You must make it `.` before casting to double:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn("% Iron Feed", F.regexp_replace("% Iron Feed", ",", ".").cast("double"))
```